# Wpf datagrid pagedown with scrolling set to pixel and tab stop set to false for cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid where I have tabbing disabled on cells and the virtualizing panel scroll unit set to pixel. When I press <kbd>PgDn</kbd> the selected item does not change and so the page down scrolling does not work as standard.

Changing either the cell tab stop to true of the virtualizing panel scroll unit to item puts the page down scrolling back to normal.

Why is this and is it possible to keep both settings while fixing the page down scrolling?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code for the `DataGrid`, you will see that it handles the `KeyDown` event for the `PageDown` key in a certain way only when the `ScrollUnit` it set to `Item`: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,1e8d30484d9b09db,references

So if you want to this to work, you will have to subclass the `DataGrid` class and override the `OnKeyDown` method to provide your own custom `PageDown` functionality. You may "steal" and modify the private `OnPageUpOrDownKeyDown` method according to your requirements.